# Nested class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

I'm a totally newbie in JavaScript, which i need for a new project. And now I have a problem:

```
var main = new function() {
    this.init = new function() {
        //access something.init();
    };
    this.something = new function () {
        this.init = function(){
        //do something
        //execute somethingother()
        };
        this.somethingother = function(){
        //do something          
        };
    };
};

main.init();
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a practical problem. It is most likely a homework to find out all that can and will go wrong.

Comment: "A very difficult homework". Now i hate you. Do your homework yourself. It good for your future =_= . No joking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to nest functions inside function - you CAN, but you should learn javascript syntax, how lexical scope and variable hoisting works, and overall - read Douglas Crockford's articles (or watch his videos).

The code you have shown will not work, try to look at my modification of it, and understand the difference.

```
var Main = function() {
    /* this function is a constructor */
    var m = this; // store scope
    // do your init stuff

    m.boringCollection = {
        /* simple object with function inside */
        /* notice JSON style formatting */
        doStuff : function(){
            //do something
        },
        doOtherStuff : function(){
            //do something else         
        };
    };
    m.coolConstructor = function () {
        var cc = this; // store scope             
        var sleep = true; // just an example variable
        cc.moveMyself = function(){
            //do something          
        };
        cc.init = function() {
            sleep = false; // just an example
            cc.moveMyself(); // will work
            cc.work(); // will FAIL, because function work is defined after its called
        };
        cc.work = function() {
            // do some work
        };
    };        
};

var main = new Main(); // make new instance of Main 
main.boringCollection.doOtherStuff(); // will work

main.coolConstructor.init(); // will NOT work 
var scrappy = new main.coolConstructor(); // make new instance of m.coolConstructor
scrappy.init(); // will work
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have classes out of the box. You need to implement classes yourself.

One popular implementation is [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/), if you don't want to write your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hmm , maybe i have used the wrong words(class). Ich want to do it in this way but i do not know how to access the other functions from main.init or main.something.init.

Comment: @FranzFinke - Javascript doesn't have classes, but it does have constructors (which are just functions called with the `new` keyword) that return object instances. Confused yet? :)

Comment: I believe, that JavaScript is not a real oop language, because it only uses objects, but not have classes ^^

Comment: You are correct that it is not a "classical" object oriented language,  it is a "prototypal" object oriented language...