# TypeError when using nested class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a stack in JavaScript that uses a nested class.

```
class Stack {
  constructor() {
    class Node {
      constructor(val, pre) {
        this.val = val;
        this.pre = pre;
      }
    }

    this.top = undefined;
  }

  push(val) {
    this.top = new Node(val, this.top);
  }

  pop() {
    let ret = this.top.val;
    this.top = this.top.pre;
    return ret;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.top === undefined;
  }
}
```

With this code I get `TypeError: Illegal constructor` as soon as the method `push()` is called.
Apparently, I can create `Node` objects only in the constructor of the stack. This is most likely because the nested class is in the constructor but putting it in directly into the other class creates syntax errors.

Does JavaScript not have nested classes like this? All I could find on the internet on nested classes were declarations of classes with the `function` keyword like this one:
[Nested class in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614967/nested-class-in-javascript)

However, that answer is before `class` was added in 2015 (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions), so I was wondering if that is possible now.

Comment: How about this answer? It was around the same time `class` was added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes

Comment: Yes, thanks! That does look like the answer to my question, I should have researched more, I did not see that one. Can I somehow close this question or redirect it to that answer or should I delete it?